# ZF2 Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Form\Element\Datetime

Tags: php, forms, datetime, zend-framework2

When i run the following code in a form class on my test domain:

```
$dateformat = "Y-m-d H:i";
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'startdatetime',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Datetime',
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'startdatetime',
        'data-format' => "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
        'min' => date($dateformat, $nowdate),
        'max' => date($dateformat, $futuredate),
        'step' => '5', // minutes; default step interval is 1 mint
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => _('Start date and time'),
        'help-block' => _('Enter start date and time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM)'),
    ),
));
$this->get('startdatetime')->setFormat($dateformat);
```

I get this error:

```
Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Form\Element\Datetime
```

When running this locally there are no errors and all works fine?
Also the Text and Textarea form elements that precedes it, work fine.

I just can't wrap my head around it...
Any ideas?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date time element [is registered with the form element manager as an invokable class called  `datetime`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/FormElementManager.php#L39). You can also use the class' fully qualified class name, which is of course case *sensitive*, `Zend\Form\Element\DateTime`.

Therefore, the only change you need to make is to uppercase the `T` in `Datetime`

```
'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\DateTime',
```

Or use the actual service name, which as with all services, is case *insensitive*.

```
'type' => 'datetime',
```

Comment: Thanks! totally missed that.